# "La femme de Dupont brise son silence sur son état" : ambiguous or not?

Tags: sens, nuance

> *"La femme de Dupont brise son silence sur son état"*.
>   Should it be understood that it conveys the meaning of
>
> "Dupont's wife breaks HER silence about HIS (state)".

or does the meaning depend rather upon the context?

Comment: I would have written: *La femme de M. Dupont brise le silence sur son état.*

Comment: @jlliagre : +1!... Sauf... si c'est à coup de scopolamine... :-)

Comment: Good question, imo. The following is OT judging by all the support for "le silence" in French but it English, "breaks HER silence" would be called for if her reason for [finally] speaking out was to put an end to all the [deafening, i.e. there was no silence to break on the matter except her own] rumors and speculation running rampant among her friends/in the media/etc.

Comment: It's totally impossible to know for sure if it's `her` state or `his` state. Now even without further context, I would say it's Dupont's state, because why would you say  "Dupont's wife" instead of using her name, if you are talking about her state? I'm not saying it's impossible of course, not at all, once again it's really ambiguous and I would avoid it, but to me mentioning Dupont suggests that you're talking about his state. And with a context I'm pretty sure it would be obvious.

Comment: @jlliagre It could very well be *La femme de Mme Dupont*

Comment: @Evpok Indeed but I ruled it out given the ***his** state*. My main point was obviously about **le** vs **son**. I took the opportunity to state that using a last name without a title can be ruder in French than in English.

Comment: Dimitris, according to SE new trend, the English meaning should be: ***Dupont's spouse breaks their silence about their state***... ;-)

Comment: *xorg* silence about *xorg* state. ʕ ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°ʔ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are indeed 2 possible translations and with only this sentence it's not possible to tell whether she's going to break silence about HIS or HER state. Now any kind of context will probably remove this ambiguity.

A way to remove this ambiguity would be to formulate it like this:

> La femme de Dupont brise le silence sur l'état de celui-ci (his state)

or

> La femme de Dupont brise le silence sur son propre état (her state)

Note that following several remarks I replaced "son silence" by "le silence" so that the sentence itself is more idiomatic. I'm not sure though whether "son silence" is less idiomatic or plainly false but I personnally find it less elegant.

EDIT:

Actually there's 4 possible translations if you consider that you don't know neither who's "silence" we talk about. That said as breaking someone else's silence is really far-fetched, I consider it quite safe to assume we're talking about the wife's silence even without further context.

Comment: Plutôt que de celui-ci j'aurais dit « de son mari ». Mais je comprends la question comme toi (cl tes commentaires ailleurs sur cette page).

Comment: “Son silence” is perfectly idiomatic. It's “brise le silence” if everybody had been quiet and she's the first to speak on the topic, and “brise son silence” if she had been quiet until now and the sentence makes no claim regarding other people's silence.

Answer (score -2):

« Briser le silence » est une expression dans laquelle le verbe « briser » est employé au sens figuré pour signifier une discontinuité dans une période de silence et ce qui apporte cette discontinuité peut être n'importe quoi qui produit du son (voix, tonnerre, moteur, cri, …). Par métaphore, cette expression prend le sens second de « faire des révélations à propos de quelque chose qui avait jusqu'alors été passé sous silence ».

On remarque que la forme « [brisa le silence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brisa+le+silence&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrisa%20le%20silence%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbrisa%20le%20silence%3B%2Cc0) » n'est utilisée pratiquement qu'avec la première acception et que la forme « [briser le silence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=briser+le+silence&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbriser%20le%20silence%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbriser%20le%20silence%3B%2Cc0) » se trouve employée en écrasante majorité avec le second sens.

« Briser le silence » (forme de base) n'est pas l'expression la plus habituelle ; c'est une récente introduction dans le langage (depuis 1920 à peu près) et qui n'est pas si souhaitable puisqu'elle autorise tout aussi bien « casser le silence » que l'on ne dit pas du tout pour l'instant. L'expression consacrée est « rompre le silence » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sortir+du+silence%2Crompre+le+silence%2Cbriser+le+silence&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csortir%20du%20silence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crompre%20le%20silence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbriser%20le%20silence%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csortir%20du%20silence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crompre%20le%20silence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbriser%20le%20silence%3B%2Cc0)), qui s'emploie de façon synonyme, c'est à dire dans les deux sens, et pour laquelle on peut constater une spécialisation similaire ([rompit le silence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rompit+le+silence&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crompit%20le%20silence%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crompit%20le%20silence%3B%2Cc0), [rompre le silence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rompre+le+silence&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crompre%20le%20silence%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crompre%20le%20silence%3B%2Cc0) —  Il faut encore une fois examiner les occurrences dans les livres pour se rendre compte de cela).

Dans le sens par métaphore, lorsque le silence figuré est maintenu par une personne qui a plus ou moins la clé à un état de chose caché (souvent un aspect ou une anecdote de sa vie personnelle, mais pas nécessairement) *et qui est plus ou moins pressée par les évènements ou des individus de faire des révélations*, on peut utiliser de façon synonyme « sortir du silence », mais seulement dans ces cas-là. Si la situation cachée est connue d'un certain groupe dont tous les membres ont la même possibilité de faire des révélations, il faut utiliser l'une des deux premières expressions.

« Briser le silence » (synonyme, « rompre ») ne signifie pas autre chose en anglais que « break the/her/ his silence » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=break+his+silence%2Cbreak+her+silence%2Cbreak+the+silence&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbreak%20his%20silence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbreak%20her%20silence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbreak%20the%20silence%3B%2Cc0)) lorsque il s'agit du silence figuré général d'un groupe ou du silence figuré de la personne qui parle et non pas du silence de quelqu'un d'autre, soit au sens littéral soit au sens figuré.
Cela est la raison qui implique qu'il ne peut pas s'agir du silence de Dupont en anglais ; en français, ce n'est pas différent : on ne rompt pas le silence de quelqu'un d'autre. Cependant on peut « sortir quelqu'un de son silence ». Pour exprimer ce sens qui pourrait être cette seconde partie d'une valeur ambivalente de « briser le silence » la phrase suivante est plus claire.

- La femme de Dupont  sortit son mari  de son silence sur l'état de celui-ci.

Néanmoins, avec ce verbe-ci il est possible de parler d'un silence littéral.

- La femme de Dupont  sortit son mari  de son silence avec un « Dépêche-toi ! » sur un ton irrité.
  (*À noter que dans ce cas, on s'abstient de mélanger les idées et on n'ajoute pas « sur son état » si en plus il était question d'un tel silence figuré.*)

COMPLÉMENT Comme l'ambiguïté entre l'état de la personne qui parle et l'état de celle de qui on parle due à « son » relève d'un savoir courant, elle n'a pas été examinée, cela surtout du fait que l'emphase sur « her » est à l'intention de contraster avec « his silence ».

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101083/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-la-femme-de-dupont-brise-son-silence-sur-son-etat).